# hibernate criteria aggregation on specific date

Tags: hibernate

How can I transform this query to hibernate criteria:

```
Select cat, sum(amount) 
from transaction 
where customer =: customer 
  and month =: month 
  and year = year 
group by cat;
```

My current criteria is :

```
 Select cat, sum(amount) 
 from transaction 
 where customer =: customer 
 group by cat; 

Criteria cx = getCriteria()
         .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.sum("amount", "amount")
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("cat", "cat")
                )
        .add(Restrictions.eq("customer", customer))
                ;
```

I have try manything such ass .add(Restrictions.eq("month(createOn)", month) but I got this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: month(createOn) of: com.transaction
```

I have make sure that I have createOn field with datatype of date, and do not syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sql Restictions **Restrictions.sqlRestriction**

```
Criteria cx = getCriteria()
     .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.sum("amount", "amount")
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("cat", "cat")
            )
    .add(Restrictions.eq("customer", customer))
    .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("YEAR(DB_DATE_COLUMN) >= ? ", year,Hibernate.INTEGER)
    .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("MONTH(DB_DATE_COLUMN) >= ? ", month,Hibernate.INTEGER)   ;
```